# I thought that downloading the Xamarin NuGet would pull all the dependencies along with it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget, nuget-package, filenotfoundexception

I installed the Xamarin NuGet into my solution and tried to run the app. 
 When I received this error

```
Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'PCLCrypto, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d4421c8a4786956c'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'PCLCrypto.dll'
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5749/75f8c683/source/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:line 229
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver) GridlockCardGame.Android
```

So I guess I'm missing an assembly somewhere, but I thought that the NuGet Manager would pull all that with the install.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please read the materials from PCLCrypto itself. It has a complex set of instructions to use, not merely just adding a NuGet package.

Comment: So why isn't that information included with the tutorials on Xamarin.com? The instructions say to simply install the NuGet package and run the app. Now you're telling me that there are complex instructions to run it.

Comment: PCLCrypto is a third party package, which does not belong to Xamarin. The changes on PCLCrypto side can easily go beyond Xamarin documentation. "Be sure to install the NuGet package into your Portable library as well as each platform-specific app that uses your portable library. If you're shipping your portable library on NuGet, be sure to specify PclCrypto as a NuGet package dependency of your own NuGet package and you're set." https://github.com/AArnott/PCLCrypto I think you missed this part. The rise of .NET Standard also makes it less useful.

Comment: Try looking into .NET Standard libraries. They allow you to use all crypto APIs without the need of a shim (=PCLCrypto). PCLs are becoming a thing of the past.

Comment: Well thank you for the info, Krumelur. I will look into the .NET Standard libraries. So I guess I'll have to find some other way to authenticate the user withing Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to manually install the PCLCrypto NuGet package into my solution and successfully run my project in the emulator.